# Proof of graph sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Why does a graph with degree sequence 1,1,2,2,2,3,4 not exist.

Where do I begin to attempt solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by handshaking theorem, the sum of all the degrees should be twice the number of edges, and so in particular it should be even which is not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is much easier to solve this problem noticing that the sum of all the degrees is odd, which is a clear contradiction. However, if the sum turned to be even, we could not say immediately if such graph exists or not. Let is proof important lemma:

> Suppose there are two non-increasing sequences: $ \textbf{d}:=(s,\;d_{1},\;d_{2},\dots,\;d_{s},\;d_{s+1},\dots,\;d_{n})$ and $\textbf{d}':=(d_{1}-1,\;d_{2}-1,\dots,\;d_{s}-1,\;d_{s+1},\dots,\;d_{n})$. Then $\textbf{d}$ is a graph sequence if and only if $\textbf{d}'$ is a graph sequence.

*Proof*: Well, if $\textbf{d}'$ is a graph sequence, then obviously $\textbf{d}$ is too. Indeed, find vertices $d_{1}-1,\;d_{2}-1,\dots,\;d_{s}-1$ then add vertex $x$ and connect $x$ with those vertices. To prove in forward direction is harder, because you can't just delete vertex $s$ as it is not necessarily connected with $d_{1}-1,\;d_{2}-1,\dots,\;d_{s}-1$. Let's delete vertex $s$ and mark vertices, that were connected with $s$, with "$-1$". Let's call vertices $d_{1}-1,\;d_{2}-1,\dots,\;d_{s}-1$ "*major*" and other vertices as "*minor*". Idea is to somehow mark unmarked major vertices and unmark marked minor ones. Let's show that we can always make this exchange. Find unmarked major vertex, say $M$, and marked minor vertex $m$. Take a look at all other vertices in our graph. I claim that there will be vertex $v$ such that $v$ is connected with $M$ but not with $m$. By contradiction: if it is not the case, then $\mathrm{deg} \;m\geq  \mathrm{deg}\;M$. Well, if $\mathrm{deg} \;m>  \mathrm{deg}\;M$ then that is a contradiction, if $\mathrm{deg} \;m=  \mathrm{deg}\;M$ then we can just exchange vertices $m$ and $M$ (or rename). Thus, such vertex $v$ is found. But then we can delete edge $vM$ and add edge $vm$ without changing degree of $v$. $\blacksquare$
For this particular problem we have $(4,3,2,2,2,1,1) \sim (2,1,1,1,1,1)\sim (0,0,1,1,1)\sim (1,1,1,0,0)\sim (1,0,0,0)$ $\rightarrow\leftarrow$